# Drools - Find matching object from a list of unconnected objects

Tags: drools, rules, business-rules

I have a Mutation class with 3 variables, m1, m2, and m3. I also have a list of independent objects of a class Strain with 1 variable v. I need to be able to match a number of these objects i a list to the variables m1, m2 and m3.

Here is the Mutation class

```
     class Mutation{
      String m1;
      String m2;
      String m3;
   }
```

The class Strain has a single variable m and is shown below:

```
   class Strain {
      String m;
   }
```

I want to find the Strains that match the mutation. Here is what I tried with no success.

```
 rule "Find the mathcing strains for the mutation"
   when
    $m: Mutation ( $m1: m1, $m2: m2, $m3: m3)
    $s1: Strain(  m == $m1  )
    $s2: Strain(  m == $m2 )
    $s3: Strain ( m == $m3)
   then
    System.out.println("Found matching Strains");
 end
```

However, this does not work. I have all the Strain objects and the Mutation objects inserted in the session. I also print out the values of the list of Mutation objects and the list of Strain objects and see the m values of the Strain objects that match the Mutation values, m1, m2 ad m3.

What am I doing wrong? Is this achievable using Drools? I'm sure it's my solution which has the problem. I would really appreciate finding a solution to this problem. I have scoured the net looking for a similar problem but haven't come across a solution that could fix this problem.

I summary, List mutations ... variables, m1,m2 and m3
           List strains ..  variable m

Please would really appreciate help in pointing me where I am going wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you inserting both, your `Mutation` and your `Strain` objects into your session?

Comment: Yes I am. I am adding them and verifying that as recommended in jboss drools 6

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your rule. My guess is that the rule is probably not being included in the `KieBase` you are using. Could you create a reproducer of this issue in a simple project and share it with us?

Comment: I found that there was another rule invalidating this one: I removed the rules 1 by 1  and the rule was triggered; thank you for confirming it should work which prompted me to separate this rule